# Passing parameters via redirect

Tags: php, url-routing, lithium

Is it possible to pass parameters via redirect? I tried a lot of options, but nothing seems to work. My latest approach is:

```
return $this->redirect(array('Users::helloworld', 'args' => array('id' => 'myId')));
```

then I created a route:

```
Router::connect('/Users/helloworld?id={:id}', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'helloworld'));
```

but all I get is `users/helloworld/myId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` is part of the routes and will be converted into an URL using the very generic route (not the one you created and don't require)

To get a *query string*, simply use the `?` key:

```
return $this->redirect(array(
    'Users::helloworld',
    '?' => array('id' => $myId)
));
// will use the route:
//    /{:controller}/{:action}/{:args}
// and generate
//    /users/helloworld?id=$myId
```

The test for that: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/tests/cases/net/http/RouteTest.php#L374-405

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a separate route to pass arguments, you could just do the following.
Lets say you want to pass 2 arguments: **$arg1** & **$arg2** to the **helloworld** action of your **Users** controller:

```
return $this->redirect(array(
'Users::helloworld',
'args' => array(
        $arg1,
        $arg2
    )
));
```